How do I upload file and pass list of dict as parameters in a POST endpoint in FastAPI?
I want the user to upload multiple files and pass parameters as a list of dict in the same endpoint. Here is the code that I am testing out:
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Body, status
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator
from typing import Optional, List
import json

app = FastAPI()


class FileUpload(BaseModel):
    name: str
    header_exists: bool
    rows_to_skip: int


class ListFileUpload(BaseModel):
    data: List[FileUpload]


@app.post("/upload")
async def file_upload(files: List[UploadFile], params: ListFileUpload):
    for file in files:
        print(file)
    print(params)


But I am getting this error:


See How to add both file and JSON body in a FastAPI POST request?

In addition to both the links provided above, you should find this helpful as well.
